# splitting a definite integral over an interval into infinitely many sub-intervals

Tags: calculus

if I break an interval $[a,b]$ into an infinite sequence of intervals $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n$ and prove that $\forall i$ the function $f$ is Reimann integrable over $I_i$ can I say that $f$ is Reimann integrable over $[a,b]$?

Comment: If you mean "Lebesgue-integrable," then no, since the sum of infinitely many finite numbers is in some cases infinite. But if you mean "Riemann-integrable," then maybe yes. $\qquad$

Comment: fixed, my bad :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. Imagine splitting $[0,1]$ into subintervals $I_n = [1/(n+1),1/n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Just because the function is integrable over $I_n$, resulting in $\int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} f = a_n$, that does not mean than $\sum a_n < \infty$.

But if you restrict to Riemann integration perhaps you can argue that $a_n \to 0$ since the interval width is shrinking...

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a definite counter-example. In the above scheme, let $f(x) = 1/x$ to get that
$$
\int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(1/n) - \ln(1/(n+1) = \ln(1+1/n)
$$
which is well defined for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+1/n),
$$
and of course both sides diverge.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! I meant Riemann integraiton but in my case I can't really control the manner I split the interval in

Comment: @Cufox please see update

Comment: awesome! thank you!